# Point Layer is Not Show When 3D Mode is Active [Cesium, OLCS, Openlayers]

Tags: openlayers, cesium, ol-cesium

I have a 3D map build with Cesium + OLCS + Openlayers. But in one case i cannot show my WMS Image Point Layer when 3D mode is active like this:
[image]

But Polygon Layer can show when 3D is active, and when 3D mode is nonactive the point layer is show
[image]

How can I show the point when 3D is active?

Here is my code for 3D

```
    let ol3d = new olcs.OLCesium({
    map: map,
    sceneOptions: {
      mapProjection: new Cesium.WebMercatorProjection(),
    },
  });

  Cesium.Ion.defaultAccessToken =
    "eyJhbG***************************";

  let scene = ol3d.getCesiumScene();
  let terrainProvider = new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({
    url: Cesium.IonResource.fromAssetId(1),
  });

  scene.terrainProvider = terrainProvider;

  Cesium.Math.setRandomNumberSeed(0);

  let osm3d = new Cesium.Cesium3DTileset({
    url: Cesium.IonResource.fromAssetId(96188),
  });

  scene.primitives.add(osm3d);

  osm3d.style = new Cesium.Cesium3DTileStyle({
    color: {
      conditions: [["true", "color('white', 0.7)"]],
    },
  });

  scene.globe.depthTestAgainstTerrain = true;

  ol3d.setEnabled(false);

  $("#maptools-3d").click(function () {
    ol3d.setEnabled(!ol3d.getEnabled());
  });
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console and network activity?  Is the WMS being requested and is the resolution and image dimensions of the request within its supported limits?

Comment: Yes, browser console is fine, netwok activity is fine. Request WMS of point is success but in mode 3D point is still not show... Point will show if mode is change to 2D mode.